# Transform a C# Expression into another Expression to be used in EF Query

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

In a .NET Core application, I have a one to many relationship like the following.

```
public class ModelBase
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : ModelBase
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : ModelBase
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual long FooId { get; set; }

    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Using EF 3.1, I need to query over `IQueryable<Bar> barQuery` in which the corresponding "Foo" is not logically Deleted.
Since this application does not use lazy loading, I must perform an inclusion to get any Foo's property in a single database call. So I am trying to implement an extension method which calls both `.Include(x => x.Foo)` and `.Where(x => !x.Foo.IsDeleted)` using a single expression.

So far, I have the following extension method implemented:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> IncludeNotDeleted<TEntity, TProperty>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath) 
        where TEntity : class 
        where TProperty : ModelBase
    {
        return query.Include(navigationPropertyPath).Where(/*Use the navigationPropertyPath to filter by IsDeleted*/);
    }
```

**Is there any way transforming the "navigationPropertyPath" into another Expression to be used inside .Where() clause. Or at least approaching this same goal through another single extension method solution?**

Then I can call `barQuery.IncludeNotDeleted(x => x.Foo)`

Comment: Re-opened to provide a EF-Core specific solution using the `MakeMemberAccess()` helper

Comment: If you are looking to filter out soft-deleted items this is the wrong way.  Look into EF-Core Global Filters or follow along with a [tutorial](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/ef-core-in-depth-soft-deleting-data-with-global-query-filters/)

Comment: @haim770 If you want to provide your own solution to a duplicate question that the existing question doesn't provide, then provide your answer to the canonical question, don't reopen a question.  Of course your solution is much worse, so I don't even see why you'd want to do that, but if it was any good, that would be the correct course of action.

Comment: @haim770 and why should someone use EFC general purpose internal helper method instead of well known custom one? moreover these helper methods are part of the `Infrastructure` namespace, so I guess not intended to be used. It says "This type is typically used by database providers (and other extensions). It is generally not used in application code."

Comment: @Servy, The other question is not about EF but LINQ in general.

Comment: @IvanStoev, It is considered "infrastructure" indeed, but the method is still `public` for this very purpose: If you already have to deal with expression-trees, do it more easily using those helpers.

Comment: @haim770 You think this isn't using LINQ?  That said, the question is tagged as EF anyway, not that it matters, as there's no good reason to use anything EF specific.

Comment: @haim770 You do realize that that method is doing literally nothing but making a static method into an extension method, right?  It's not like it's doing anything particularly complex or interesting, it's just a different way to call `Expression.MakeMemberAccess`.  And of course constructing the expressions by hand like this should be avoided at all costs, and it can and should absolutely be avoided here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the following method to generate the modified `Expression`:

```
private static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> GeneratePredicate<TEntity, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> src)
    where TEntity : class
    where TProperty : ModelBase
{
    var isDeletedPropExpr = src.Body.MakeMemberAccess(typeof(ModelBase).GetMember(nameof(ModelBase.IsDeleted)).First());
    var newBody = Expression.Equal(isDeletedPropExpr, Expression.Constant(false));
    
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(newBody, src.Parameters[0]);
}
```

Then integrate it into your extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> IncludeNotDeleted<TEntity, TProperty>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath)
        where TEntity : class
        where TProperty : ModelBase
{
    var predicate = GeneratePredicate(navigationPropertyPath);
    return query.Include(navigationPropertyPath).Where(predicate);
}
```

The above uses the [`MakeMemberAccess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.expressionextensions.makememberaccess?view=efcore-5.0) helper method provided by EF Core.

Comment: As good as this answer is, you should probably mention that soft-deletes can be handled more efficiently manner using global filters